# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to run an application but not able to build an app, getting following error Snap is

[image]

I have show and follow link to solved error but not solved this error

[Why am I getting ibtool failed with exit code 255?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15422033/5593725)

[(xcode 5) ibtool failed with exit code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20531240/5593725)

[Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19463383/5593725)

Comment: 1. Goto Library --> Developer --> Xcode --> DerivedData  then delete all the folders in it.
2. Then Clean the project and run it will work.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota, I have also remove the Derived data but not solved this - `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255` error!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen to us and we clean cache, delete Derived data folder.. etc. Nothing happen.

Below steps did it fix,

1. Open xib (nib) as Source Code (Right click on the xib Open As >
   Source Code from Xcode or open it using TextEdit)
2. remove this **appearanceType="aqua"**
3. save and open using Xcode

For more explain use this [article](http://www.tyreeapps.com/blog/tools/2014/06/10/Xcode-Crash-with-xib-Files.html), it help us to fix the issue.

Comment: @vyas if this is right answer than accept it as correct answer.